# Импорт cookies в selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, cookie

У меня есть txt файл с выгруженными cookies в таком виде:

```
         .atdmt.com TRUE    /   TRUE    1648574654  ATN    1.1585502654.11271001489898199409.AYKs5NurcbOFWrw_UfM

www.expressvpn.com  FALSE   /   TRUE    1617038652  xvid    RwgvYTpwRV3nqR-OhlDHkZ_D7c_8jRn5DBL7swBzwtI%3D

.safervpn.com   TRUE    /   TRUE    1616606686  funnelAb
```

мне нужно загрузить эти куки в chrome/firefox браузер,
как я понял я должен каким-то образом сериализовать эту информацию для последующей выгрузки в `browser.add_cookie(cookies)`

Answer (score 0):

оказалось, что это формат netscape , с этой информацией уже можно работать дальше